# Отправить массив через ajax в api controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Я хочу отправить через ajax массив и обработать его в контролле, но массив приходит пустым. Где может быть ошибка?

Скрипт

```
  <script>
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Values));
$("#nextbtn").click("on",
    function ()
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/api/Channel',
                type: 'POST',

                contentType: 'application/json', 

                data: { '':JSON.stringify(model) },
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#results").html(result);
                }
            }
            );
    }
    );
```

Кусок разметки страницы

```
@model IDictionary<int, Applience>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" id="nextbtn">-></button>

    <br />
    <div id="results"></div>
```

api controller

```
public string PostNext(List<Applience> model)
    {
       IChannel tv= model.FirstOrDefault(m => m is IChannel) as IChannel;
       tv.NextChannel();
       return tv.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: вы вроде хотите массив отправить, зачем же вы его в объект запихиваете, с каким-то пустым ключом при этом. просто `data: model`. В строку переводить тут тоже не надо ничего.
Либо если параметр надо именовать, то `data : {'model' : model}`

Comment: @ teran, я много вариантов пробовала как передать массив(с ключом как параметр в контролле, без перевода в строку) и не один не работал. Можете, подсказать как правильно это сделать?

Comment: попробуйте свериться с этим мануалом http://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/2.7.php